# I need to change the image displayed by a JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I have a class that extends JButton and I want to change the Background image that a button created from a new instance of that class will display. I cant say i know a whole lot about programming as I am self taught and i haven't been working on it for too long so i just know the basics. I believe I have to create an icon of the image then apply it or create a buffredImage from the file and apply it though im not quite sure how to do so. Ive looked at various other similar questions but i see many classes and methods im unfamiliar with and when i try to implement them my IDE cant find them (Most likely because im not sure what files to import to get them in my program). Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display an image, use the `ImageIcon` class, inserted into a `JLabel`.

You also need to read the image from disk in some way. Set your `JButton` to action upon the JLabel.

This question will help you with actually retrieving the image: [How to change icon of a JLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567445/how-to-change-icon-of-a-jlabel) . However, it's basically something like

```
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("/path/to/icon");
ImageIcon icon;
if (imgURL != null) {
    icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
} else {
    System.err.println("Couldn't find icon path");
}
```

Take a look at: [How to Use Icons (Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

And then this may be placed into your JLabel by either:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon)
```

or (when it is already initialised)

```
label.setImageIcon(icon);
```

### Resizing an ImageIcon

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this works mostly, though is there a way to stretch/shrink the image to fully fill the label?

Comment: Yeah. You need to know the size you need. "width" and "height" are specified by you in this case. If you only want to specify one, leave the other as "-1" and it's scaled correctly. The code is in the updated answer.