# Changing JLabel icon dynamically after already adding to GUI?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jpanel, jlabel

I'm having trouble changing an icon deep in my GUI using Swing components. I'm creating a chess game for fun with Java and want the right side of the GUI to respond when a piece is taken by showing the taken piece in a grid.  My problem is that whenever I call the `setIcon()` function within `JLabel` with a new image and add it to the appropriate `JPanel`, it does not update. It works when I `setIcon()` the first time, but after it is added to the GUI, I can't change it the way I have been trying to. Here is screenshots so you know what I'm getting at:

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAWCM.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoJJU.jpg)

As you can tell, a pawn has been taken but the right panel does not reflect this despite my efforts.

I did some research and the following question was similar: [Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567445/how-to-change-icon-of-a-jlabel)

Camickr responded in that saying it could be two instances of the JLabel I am trying to update which I believe is what is going in my case.  I initially set all of my icons on the right panel to null when setting the GUI up for initial state. Here is the code that does this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    piece1Labels[i] = new JLabel();
    piece2Labels[i] = new JLabel();
    piece1Panels[i] = new ChessSpace(playerDeadPieceTile);
    piece2Panels[i] = new ChessSpace(playerDeadPieceTile);
    piece1Labels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(67,66));
    piece2Labels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(67,66));
    piece1Labels[i].setIcon(null);
    piece2Labels[i].setIcon(null);
    piece1Panels[i].add(piece1Labels[i]);
    piece2Panels[i].add(piece2Labels[i]);
    player1PiecePanel.add(piece1Panels[i]);
    player2PiecePanel.add(piece2Panels[i]);
}
```

and here is me trying to change one of those panels after the initialization has been called on the first panel in the piece1Panels array of `ChessSpace` which extend `JPanel`:

```
//Try to change right panel icon after GUI setup
    piece1Labels[0] = new JLabel();
    piece1Panels[0] = new ChessSpace(playerDeadPieceTile);
    piece1Labels[0].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(67,66));
    piece1Labels[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Shasta/workspacejava/chess/images/terranpawn.jpg"));
    piece1Panels[0].add(piece1Labels[0]);
```

piece1Labels and piece1Panels are variables of a class extending `JFrame`. I believe that the problem is that I'm just updating the class variable and not updating the instance that was added to the GUI.

EDIT:
As Alican Ozgoren & Hovercraft Full Of Eels pointed out I shouldn't have declared new instances of the `JLabel`, they were redundant.

The following line of code seems to do what I want:

```
//Try to change right panel icon after GUI setup
    piece1Labels[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Shasta/workspacejava/chess/images/terranpawn.jpg"));
```

Comment: Why create a new JLabel everytime you want to change the icon, size etc.? Change the existing label's prefs. Also, did you try to call `repaint()` after you made your changes?

Comment: As @AlicanOzgoren states, you shouldn't create new JLabels for this purpose, but rather simply change the current JLabel's Icon via its `setIcon(Icon icon)` method. Do this and there's no need to even call `repaint()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we noted, simply set the Icon of the JLabel. But one more thing -- don't keep reading in the Icons as you're doing here:

```
piece1Labels[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(
         "C:/Users/Shasta/workspacejava/chess/images/terranpawn.jpg"));
```

Instead read the Icons in once at the beginning of your program, and store them in variables so that you get:

```
piece1Labels[0].setIcon(terranpawnIcon);
```

I would also read them in as resources not Files so that you can later store your images in your jar file and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a thread which will update the JLable Icone please see the code below

package self.wing.practice.image;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * 
 * @author ASHISH KUMAR MISHRA
 * 
 */
public class ImageDemo {

```
public ImageDemo() {
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Image Demo");
    jfrm.setSize(200, 150);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    jfrm.add(label);
    new ImageUpdator(label).start();
    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new ImageDemo();
        }
    });
}
```

}

i have created a thread to whom i am passing a Jlabel in Constructur. see below the what my thread is doing

package self.wing.practice.image;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 * 
 * @author ASHISH KUMAR MISHRA
 * 
 */
public class ImageUpdator extends Thread {

```
String imagePath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures";
File imageDir = new File(imagePath);
JLabel label = null;

ImageUpdator(JLabel label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public void run() {

    ImageIcon imageIcon = null;

    if (imageDir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = imageDir.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            i = i % files.length;
            File currentFile = files[i];
            if (currentFile.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                ;
            {
                imageIcon = new ImageIcon(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                label.setName(currentFile.getName().substring(0,
                        currentFile.getName().indexOf('.')));
                label.setIcon(imageIcon);
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

### Heading